# Camera view goes black

Tags: camera

I could not find any solution. My camera view is totally black.

Render results are ok, but I cannot see anything through the camera. No borders, no objects. It is not about the shortkeys. I think clipping is fine. Through the camera I cannot see anything.

[image]

[image]

Comment: hello could you please share your file (just keep the minimum, the camera + a cube for example)?

Comment: Have you tried to lower the value of your nearclip ?
Also, try to get into your camera view (View Camera with numpad 0 key). 
What happens if you scroll from your 3D viewport where you should see your camera point of view?

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>Home</kbd> (View → Cameras → Frame Camera Bounds ) to reset the camera view.

Comment: Thank you very much! That solved my problem!